# WordPress Global Redirect

Tags: redirect, wp-redirect

I need to expand on this discussion [Redirect entire website to a single page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/76802/redirect-entire-website-to-a-single-page) to include two pages rather than one.

On this site, I need two pages to be live and all others to redirect to the home page.

http://prairiebrand.com/

This is the code I'm trying and I get a perpetual redirect.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse_76802_goodbye_redirect' );

    function wpse_76802_goodbye_redirect() {
        if (( ! is_page( 16372 ) ) || ( ! is_page( 16384 ) )) {
            wp_redirect( esc_url_raw( home_url( 'index.php?page_id=16372' ), 301 ) );
            exit;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_page()` supports array too, so you could do something like this.

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse_76802_goodbye_redirect' );

function wpse_76802_goodbye_redirect() {
    if ( !is_page( array( 16372, 16384 ))) {
        wp_redirect( esc_url_raw( home_url( 'index.php?page_id=16372' ), 301 ) );
        exit;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code throws this error:

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /nfs/c09/h01/mnt/130406/domains/prairiebrand.com/html/wp-content/themes/prairie-brand-3.1/functions.php on line 323

Comment: Everything looks correct though.

Comment: Check your funcions.php on line 323, to check the unexpected '{', when I am not sure I simply remove the code, save to check everything is ok and then simply add it at the bottom.

Comment: I ")" was actually missing in this line: if ( !is_page( array( 16372, 16384 ) ) {.  I will correct it for future visitors

Thanks for help!

Comment: You're right, glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

You have invalid condition. Change `||` to `&&` (otherwise `if` always will be TRUE):

```
if ( !is_page( 16372 ) && !is_page( 16384 ) )
```

This mean: if current page ID is not 16372 **AND** is not 16384 then redirect.

Full code:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse_76802_goodbye_redirect' );

function wpse_76802_goodbye_redirect() {
    if ( !is_page( 16372 ) && !is_page( 16384 ) ) {
        wp_redirect( esc_url_raw( home_url( 'index.php?page_id=16372' ), 301) );
        exit;
    }
}
```